# css - why div margin top in print blurred

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I want to making a page for barcode label prints with bixolon printer,

So now I made an example page for testing it,

In chrome print preview configuration, I set margin to none and I set width 10cm and height 2cm,

My elements (`div`)s no have any `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` means these properties have `0px` as value and they have `height` with 2cm value as the print pages size that I set in browser print preview config,

 and I set the border none in print,
[image]

So I think the elements must be fixed in each page slices without any mess,

But in print preview after some pages there are some vertical distances blurred between divs.
[image]

here these my styles:

```
        @media print {
    .controls
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .label-box,.label-item{
        border: 0 !important;
        border-style: hidden !important;
    }
    * {
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; /*Chrome, Safari */
        color-adjust: exact !important;  /*Firefox*/
    }
}
.controls{
    width: 50%;
    direction: rtl;
    margin: auto auto;
}
.paper > div{
    /*width: 2in;*/
    /*height: 0.75in;*/
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
input{
    display: block;
    color: #000 !important;
}
.paper{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto auto;
    display: table;
}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}


input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.label-box{
    border: 1px solid;
    border-style: dotted;
    position:relative;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: center center !important;
}
.label-item{
    min-height: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 10px;
    direction: rtl;
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 2px 0;
    line-height: 1.2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Old versions of Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome, Edge, Opera and Firefox */
}
aside {
    position:  absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0; 
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.66);
    /*border: 2px  solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);*/
    border-radius: 0px; padding: 8px;
}
#barcode_box{
    position: relative;
}
#barcode_box img{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

And this is my html code:

```
<div class="paper"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><br style="clear: both;"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><br style="clear: both;"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><br style="clear: both;"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><br style="clear: both;"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><br style="clear: both;"><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div><div class="element"><div class="barcode-label-container"><div class="barcode-label"><div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.2cm;"><aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:10px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEZJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Qw2DPEP9AfkP7H/sH/D/AGHmfwwf2A8wfvgPFAFKMf7/UQNkjKoeVT2qelT1qOpR1aOqR1UPadUApLaHz3y/puAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="100%" height="18px"></aside><aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">رنگ پارچه 30 میل سبز هور</aside><aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.45cm;right:0cm;font-size:10px;">خرید هر عدد</aside></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Whats wrong in my process?

Can anyone help me for my problem??

Comment: I put your code in an HTML file and did not see any problem. Use height instead of margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed bixolon driver,

 and I config paper size to `width:10cm` and `height:2cm` in the printer driver,

 And I set below style in css:

```
 @media print 
 {
 @page {
 size: 10cm 2cm;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
}
.element
{
 display:inline-table;
}
```

and in html I changed my html divs to table tag structure like :

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="element">
   <div class="barcode-label-container">
   <div class="barcode-label">
   <div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0cm;">
   <aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:12px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEtJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Q/3B//w/GOT/s///J8///w8DP3vzP4YP7AcYP4AYDPUHGP//qLF/wDCqelT1qOpR1aOqR1WPqh5VPaRVAwCkdWf5Rk3PnAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="18px"></aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">کاغذ دکوپاژ طرح کاشی سایز A4 کد 6209</aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.35cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">خرید هر بسته</aside></div></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="element">
   <div class="barcode-label-container">
   <div class="barcode-label">
   <div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.3cm;">
   <aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:12px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEtJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Q/3B//w/GOT/s///J8///w8DP3vzP4YP7AcYP4AYDPUHGP//qLF/wDCqelT1qOpR1aOqR1WPqh5VPaRVAwCkdWf5Rk3PnAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="18px"></aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">کاغذ دکوپاژ طرح کاشی سایز A4 کد 6209</aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.35cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">خرید هر بسته</aside></div></div></div>
   </td>
   <td class="element">
   <div class="barcode-label-container">
   <div class="barcode-label">
   <div class="label-box" style="width:3cm;height:2cm;background-image:url()!important;margin-top:0cm;margin-left:0.3cm;">
   <aside draggable="true" id="barcode_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0.5cm;right:0cm;width:cm;height:1cm;font-size:12px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAWMAAAAyAQMAAACzqShEAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAAEtJREFUSIlj+N9+QP4/Q/3B//w/GOT/s///J8///w8DP3vzP4YP7AcYP4AYDPUHGP//qLF/wDCqelT1qOpR1aOqR1WPqh5VPaRVAwCkdWf5Rk3PnAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100%" height="18px"></aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="product_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:0cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">کاغذ دکوپاژ طرح کاشی سایز A4 کد 6209</aside>
   <aside draggable="true" id="pack_title_box" class="label-item" style="display:block;top:1.35cm;right:0cm;font-size:12px;">خرید هر بسته</aside></div></div></div>
   </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

So my problem is solved.

Comment: Hi, I have some questions. The printer paper size is 8cm. why did you use 10cm? And which Persian font did you use?

Comment: I don't remember clearly, but I'm sure that printer model had 10cm size for width, and about font on the photos I think it's a web default font I was used for my sample but I use Iran-Sans generally.